# HTACCESS - Condição de exclusão de diretório

Tags: php, regex, htaccess

Boa noite!

Estou com o seguinte cenário em uma aplicação:

Estou redirecionando todos os requests para meu index.php e tratando as URL's através da aplicação:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|etc|flv|swf|mp4|mov|ttf)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (^.*) index.php [L]
```

Eu sou péssimo com expressões regulares, até hoje não entendi essa linguagem alienígena, mas preciso muito resolver esse problema.
Todo meu frontoffice está preparado para URL Friendly, mas o admin não, então precisava que essa regra não se aplicasse ao diretório admin.
Quando eu envio parâmetros para /admin/?Area=Login, por exemplo, funciona. Se eu digito apenas /admin/ o apache aplica a regra. Se eu passo um parâmetro que seja via GET o apache não aplica.

Obrigado desde já,
Renan Mazo

Comment: Acrescente essa antes do resto: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/caminhoExcecao`

Answer (score 2):

Adicione um arquivo .htaccess na pasta /admin/

Nesse arquivo, apenas coloque o comando para desativar o mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Comment: Daniel, tentei mas não foi. Acredito que como o .htaccess pai trata todas as URL's, o diretório /admin/ nem chega a ser acessado, tornando o .htaccess dele inútil, não?

Comment: Poste na sua pergunta, o conteúdo do htaccess da pasta raíz.

Comment: ????????????????

Comment: Esse que postei é o conteúdo do .htaccess que está na htdocs.

Comment: Valeu, Daniel. O meu caso similar ao do Renan, e colocando outro htaccess no folder que eu queria, funcionou. Já estava até pensando em fazer uma gambi, de colocar o PHP a gravar exceções permitindo acesso nos folders que eu queria. :D